# how to scrape webpage after finding element by xpath and clicking on it

Tags: python-3.x, selenium-webdriver, beautifulsoup, selenium-chromedriver

```
from selenium import webdriver

from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
driver = webdriver.Chrome(r"C:\Users\Matang\Desktop\chromedriver_win32 (1)\chromedriver.exe")
driver.get("https://turo.com/search?airportCode=EWR&customDelivery=true&defaultZoomLevel=11&endDate=04%2F05%2F2019&endTime=11%3A00&international=true&isMapSearch=false&itemsPerPage=200&location=EWR&locationType=Airport&maximumDistanceInMiles=30&sortType=RELEVANCE&startDate=03%2F05%2F2019&startTime=10%3A00")
driver.find_element_by_xpath("""//*[@id="pageContainer-content"]/div[4]/div/div[1]/div[2]/div[1]/div/div/div[1]/div/div[1]/div/div/a""").click()
```

i want to get information of the page of xpath above and extract it
i always get info of the url 
please help someone

url is 
https://turo.com/search?airportCode=EWR&customDelivery=true&defaultZoomLevel=11&endDate=04%2F05%2F2019&endTime=11%3A00&international=true&isMapSearch=false&itemsPerPage=200&location=EWR&locationType=Airport&maximumDistanceInMiles=30&sortType=RELEVANCE&startDate=03%2F05%2F2019&startTime=10%3A00

Comment: Explain your question in simple and elegant way so that others will understand more easily

Answer (score 0):

After you click, it's just a matter of grabbing the html source and then parsing. You can do that with Selenium, or I prefer BeautifulSoup just because I am more familiar with it. So you would put the code here:

```
from selenium import webdriver


from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
driver = webdriver.Chrome(r"C:\Users\Matang\Desktop\chromedriver_win32 (1)\chromedriver.exe")
driver.get("https://turo.com/search?airportCode=EWR&customDelivery=true&defaultZoomLevel=11&endDate=04%2F05%2F2019&endTime=11%3A00&international=true&isMapSearch=false&itemsPerPage=200&location=EWR&locationType=Airport&maximumDistanceInMiles=30&sortType=RELEVANCE&startDate=03%2F05%2F2019&startTime=10%3A00")
driver.find_element_by_xpath("""//*[@id="pageContainer-content"]/div[4]/div/div[1]/div[2]/div[1]/div/div/div[1]/div/div[1]/div/div/a""").click()

soup = BeautifulSoup(driver.page_source, 'html.parser')

# Start finding and grabbing the tags and elements in `soup`
```

Comment: thank u for your reply but i want to know from which page it will parse i want to parse the xpaths page

Comment: it'll parse the page that it goes to after you "click"